# Join two table with where

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two queries from two views

Query 1:

```
SELECT sum(cancels) as cancelcount,codeprogram 
FROM CanceliTems 
WHERE date_save BETWEEN '1/21/2022' AND 
'2/20/2022' and usercode = 8066
GROUP By codeprogram
```

and the result is:

| cancelcount | codeprogram |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | 3001 |
| 7 | 3002 |
| 2 | 3006 |

Query 2:

```
SELECT SUM(sellcount) sellcount,codeprogram,price 
FROM sells
WHERE date_save BETWEEN '1/21/2022' AND '2/20/2022' and usercode = 8066
GROUP By codeprogram,price
```

and the result is:

| sellcount | codeprogram | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 27 | 3001 | 10000 |
| 25 | 3000 | 20000 |
| 9 | 3006 | 25000 |
| 3 | 3011 | 15000 |
| 8 | 3008 | 11000 |
| 55 | 3002 | 50000 |

How can I join two views and then subtract the number of cancel from the number of sales and finally multiply the number by the price, At a specified date range?

In every view I have field date_save (datetime) and it filled by getdate() and usercode.

**finalcount = (sellcount - cancelcount) * price**

I want the final output to be as follows:

| finalcount | codeprogram | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 3001 | 200000 |
| 25 | 3000 | 500000 |
| 7 | 3006 | 175000 |
| 3 | 3011 | 45000 |
| 8 | 3008 | 88000 |
| 47 | 3002 | 2350000 |

Thanks

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: @D-Shih is Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Please edit your post and include actual source data sample from the respective view.  You refer to sells vs cancels for the net, but then want to multiply by a price and given date.  We can't see such additional columns to support.   So, even if fake data, we need enough to SIMULATE what you are looking for, and also what you EXPECT to get back as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can try to use two subqueries with `OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT sellcount - ISNULL(cancelcount,0) finalcount,
       t1.codeprogram,
       t1.price
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(sellcount) sellcount,codeprogram,price 
    FROM sells
    WHERE date_save BETWEEN '1/21/2022' AND '2/20/2022' and usercode = 8066
    GROUP By codeprogram,price
) t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT sum(cancels) as cancelcount,codeprogram 
    FROM CanceliTems 
    WHERE date_save BETWEEN '1/21/2022' AND '2/20/2022' and usercode = 8066
    GROUP By codeprogram
) t2 ON t1.codeprogram = t2.codeprogram
```

From your query, you might rewrite as below, use `UNION ALL` combine `sells` & `CanceliTems` and make a flag to represent that 1 is
positive number, 2 is negative number then use condition aggregate function.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN flag = 1 THEN sellcount ELSE - sellcount END),codeprogram,SUM(price) price
FROM (
    SELECT sellcount,codeprogram,price , 1 flag
    FROM sells
    WHERE date_save BETWEEN '1/21/2022' AND '2/20/2022' and usercode = 8066
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cancels,codeprogram,0 , 2
    FROM CanceliTems
    WHERE date_save BETWEEN '1/21/2022' AND '2/20/2022' and usercode = 8066
) t1
GROUP BY codeprogram
```